# Installing utorrent on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation

I want to install utorrent but unfortunately it is not available in software center. So please tell me how to do so using terminal.

Comment: Why not use alternatives, like `transmission`.

Answer (score 0):

Download client

```
wget http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-21701.tar.gz
```

Unpack

```
tar xvfz utorrent-server-3.0-21701.tar.gz
```

Change directory

```
cd bittorrent-server-v3_0/
```

Start server

```
./utserver
```

Open your browser

```
http://localhost:8080/gui/
```

Login:admin

Comment: ankit@ankit-desktop:~$ wget http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-21701.tar.gz
--2013-11-02 13:43:39--  http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-21701.tar.gz
Resolving download.utorrent.com (download.utorrent.com)... 67.215.233.132
Connecting to download.utorrent.com (download.utorrent.com)|67.215.233.132|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-11-02 13:44:09 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: @Ankit Just take it from factory: http://www.utorrent.com.

Comment: When I try to get it from there a page comes with '404 Not Found'